# Editing my vimrc file on a mac

Tags: vim

I'm using Mac OSX (10.9) and I'm trying to configure my vimrc file by adding "set number". I found my vimrc file in user/share/vim/ but I can't edit it because it's read-only. How can I fix this and read it?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, guys, stop it. If you want to open the `vimrc` file you can do it by typing: `sudo vim ./vimrc` in the `user/share/vim` folder

Comment: This question concerns editing the system vim file v.s. the user-created vim file on Mac. How is it a duplicate of the supposed "No vimrc, gvimrc and .vim on mac" post?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You should not overwrite the system vimrc for various reasons. One being that with a system upgrade it will be overwritten.

Instead you can create a new .vimrc file in your home directory. Open the terminal and enter:

```
 vim ~/.vimrc
```

There you can enter your various configurations. When done, you need to save the file and restart vim.

To be sure which vimrc is being used, you can ask inside of vim by typing:

```
 :echo $MYVIMRC
```

Comment: So to emphasize, `/usr/share/vim/.vimrc` is not "your" file; anything outside of `/home/you` is a system file which you should not muck with in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: On my own computer, as `root` I want to be able to muck with whatever I want. And I wanted vim to behave uniformly regardless if I was `root` or any other user. So, it would be logical to set certain things globally instead of having a number of user-specific config files.
All in all, the original question is not answered.

Comment: @SzilardBarany yeah and we agree it is your file if it's your computer, maybe this will help , in the case eg of a mac where eg `sudo vim /usr/share/vim/.vimrc` doesn't cut it  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359319/how-can-i-edit-the-default-vimrc-file-its-read-only-and-chown-and-chmod-says/359321#359321

Comment: @Munen. Thank you for the comment. A question: once you have created the .vimrc file, how do you do to access it (find it) and edit it?

Comment: @ecjb I'm not sure I understand the question. If you're asking how I find the file, my answer is that the `.vimrc` file for your logged in user will be in the home directory of said user. Therefore, I'd find and edit it using this command: `vim ~/.vimrc`

Comment: Many thanks @Munen. I had indeed tried `vim ~/.vimrc` and it worked. many thanks!